# Does optional typename apply to concept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

GCC implemented [P0634R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) that discards the need of specifying `typename` when the type is in known context.

Does it apply to `concept` as well?

Because the following code does not compile:

```
template<typename T>
concept sample_concept =
    std::default_initializable<T::value_type> &&
    requires (T t) {
        { t.some_func(std::declval<T::some_type>()) }
            -> std::same_as<T::iterator>;
    };
```

But when I specify `typename` in front of `T::value_type` and `T::iterator`, it compiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the paper, emphasis mine:

> We therefore propose we make `typename` optional in a number of commonplace contexts that are **known to only permit type names**.

That paper makes `typename` optional only in those places where you *need* to have a type. On the right-hand side of an alias declaration, needs to be a type. In a `static_cast`, needs to be a type, etc.

But here:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept sample_concept = std::default_initializable<T::value_type>;
```

That's not the case. While `default_initializable`'s parameter is a type parameter, you can have concepts which take non-type template parameters or template template parameters too. So it's not a situation that only permits type names, so `typename` is still mandatory here.

You could ask: well, *specifically* in concepts, since you cannot overload a concept or (currently) have dependent concepts, you could just look in the concept and see if it takes a type or not. But that's a big increase in complexity for a small amount of gain, which would become both more complex and smaller if we ever added dependent concepts in the future anyway.